# How to get corresponding output text file for each input file,while extracting data from json file.?

Tags: python, json, data-extraction

I have written a script in python, which works on a multiple file,but ouput I am getting in one file. I want to get output for each file separately.

import json
import os

```
files = os.listdir('C:/Users/123456/Desktop/Ten sample /Ten sample ')# path_to_json 
for FILE in files:
    if FILE.endswith('.json'):
       with open(FILE) as json_data:
            data = json.load(json_data)
            for r in (data['elements']): #print(r['types'], r['categories'])
                for t in r['types']:
                    for c in r['categories']:

                        output = ("Type:label:", t.get('label'),  "Category:label:", c.get('label'))
```

Comment: The question is not at all clear. Please update the question, with what exactly you require

Comment: I am working on a code to run a script on multiple files in a folder. I am able to run the code on each file however it is only saving to one output file then rewriting over that file. How can I get this code to save the output to separate files? Preferably with a similar name to each original file. This is what I have thus far.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to do,

but I think this may help you:

```py
files = os.listdir('C:/Users/123456/Desktop/Ten sample /Ten sample ')# path_to_json 
for FILE in files:
    if FILE.endswith('.json'):
       with open(FILE) as json_data:
            data = json.load(json_data)
            for r in (data['elements']): #print(r['types'], r['categories'])
                for t in r['types']:
                    for c in r['categories']:

                        output = ("Type:label:", t.get('label'),  "Category:label:", c.get('label'))
                        new_file_name = FILE[:-5] + '.txt'
                        f = open(new_file_name, 'w+') 
                        f.write(output) 
                        f.close()
```